# How to partially avoid printing in ggplot?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, plot, printing

Let's consider these two functions:

`function_1` prints one plot

```
function_1 <- function() {
  print(ggplot() + aes(x=1:10, y = 1:10) + geom_line())
}

function_1()
```

[image]

Prints two side by side plots created by `function_1`

```
function_2 <- function() {
  patchwork::wrap_plots(function_1(), function_1())
}
function_2()
```

[image]

But - before this 2 side by side plots I get two plots created from `function_1` i.e. by calling `function_2` I obtain three plots:

1. Plot from `function_1`
2. Plot from `function_1`
3. Side by side plot of two plots from `function_1`.

My question is: How can I delete first two and only output third plot i.e. that `function_2` will only output side by side plots without previously printing another plots. I want to do it by only redefining `function_2` (I know that we can only delete `print()` from `function_1` and the problem is over, however it's a part of very big function of mine and I would like to deal with this problem with only considering changes in `function_2`).

**Summarize of the problem**

How to make `function_2` to plot only side by side plots (it's the third of three plots that `function_2` is making), ignoring first two created plots ?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that preserve's `function_1`'s current behavior but allows a way to disarm it:

```r
function_1 <- function(plot=TRUE) {
  gg <- ggplot() + aes(x=1:10, y = 1:10) + geom_line()
  if (plot) print(gg)
  gg
}
function_2 <- function() {
  patchwork::wrap_plots(function_1(plot=FALSE), function_1(plot=FALSE))
}
```

Comment: Hey r2evans! Thank you for your answer ;)) But as I wrote in my question - I'm interested only in solution which redefines function_2 (in my question I also noticed that omiting print formula in function_1 solves the problem)

Comment: I want to do not touch function_1 at all

Comment: If `function_1` is implicitly `print`ing the grob, then that function is broken (imo). (Sorry, I now see your note in the question about wanting to not change 1, missed it the first time.)

Comment: Since you own `function_1`, an alternative: add to it an argument `plot=TRUE` that stores `gg <- ggplot(.......)`, and then `if (plot) print(gg)`. In `function_2`, call `function_1(plot=FALSE)`. Just a thought.

Comment: Hmm could you please add it as an answer ? I don't fully understand the outline of the solution